# Class in different file cannot be found "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, header-files

Hey so I'm a beginner and wanted to do my class in another file but it can't be found. Here are the 3 files

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(){

    MyClass my_class;


    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

MyClass::MyClass(){
    std::cout << "Construtor" << std::endl;
}

MyClass::~MyClass(){
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H


class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

The console output is

```
No such file or directory
No such file or directory
error: no input file
```

The header file is in the same folder as the main and MyClass file. I can't find anything c++ related only javascript or python. Thx for help i appreciate it.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your compile command, not with code. How do you compile your code?

Comment: I use Codeblocks IDE and i don't know if thats a compiler or not but it think it uses GCC

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i use GCC compiler

Comment: Please copy and paste the command you use to compile code. Also, please tell us where the files to compile are located (relative to your working directory).

Comment: Hmm that is a weird way to compile code just saying usually we just type make....